# Cannot add .php with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm working on a web project in directory ~/public_html/foo and I'm trying to rewrite URL:s so that the extension .php is automatically added. For the file bar.php in the project directory I can access

```
http://localhost/~august/foo/bar.php
```

but when I try to access

```
http://localhost/~august/foo/bar
```

I get a 404 saying

```
The requested URL /home/august/public_html/foo/bar.php was not found on this server.
```

Here is the content of ~/public_html/foo/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php
```

and these messages show up in the error log:

```
[Sun Mar 09 16:04:12.339671 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21219] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:36432] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f193916dd80][rid#7f19390260a0/initial] [perdir /home/august/public_html/foo/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/august/public_html/foo/bar -> bar
[Sun Mar 09 16:04:12.339742 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21219] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:36432] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f193916dd80][rid#7f19390260a0/initial] [perdir /home/august/public_html/foo/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'bar'
[Sun Mar 09 16:04:12.339765 2014] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 21219] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:36432] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f193916dd80][rid#7f19390260a0/initial] [perdir /home/august/public_html/foo/] RewriteCond: input='/home/august/public_html/foo/bar' pattern='!-d' => matched
[Sun Mar 09 16:04:12.339781 2014] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 21219] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:36432] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f193916dd80][rid#7f19390260a0/initial] [perdir /home/august/public_html/foo/] RewriteCond: input='/home/august/public_html/foo/bar' pattern='!-f' => matched
[Sun Mar 09 16:04:12.339796 2014] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 21219] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:36432] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f193916dd80][rid#7f19390260a0/initial] [perdir /home/august/public_html/foo/] RewriteCond: input='/home/august/public_html/foo/bar.php' pattern='-f' => matched
[Sun Mar 09 16:04:12.339808 2014] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 21219] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:36432] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f193916dd80][rid#7f19390260a0/initial] [perdir /home/august/public_html/foo/] rewrite 'bar' -> 'bar.php'
[Sun Mar 09 16:04:12.339821 2014] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 21219] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:36432] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f193916dd80][rid#7f19390260a0/initial] [perdir /home/august/public_html/foo/] add per-dir prefix: bar.php -> /home/august/public_html/foo/bar.php
[Sun Mar 09 16:04:12.339835 2014] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 21219] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 127.0.0.1:36432] 127.0.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#7f193916dd80][rid#7f19390260a0/initial] [perdir /home/august/public_html/foo/] internal redirect with /home/august/public_html/foo/bar.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding

```
RewriteBase /~august/foo
```

after the line `RewriteEngine On`.